# Создание пользователя в postgres

Tags: postgresql

Мне дали доступ к машине, на которой стоит `CentOS 8`. На машине есть постгрес. У меня есть root-права. Зайти в саму БД я не могу. В БД не создан пользователь. Как решить этот вопрос?

Comment: "Как решить этот вопрос?" — какой вопрос? Читал Ваш текст несколько раз, ясности нет.

Comment: @IgorR. пожалуйста. Отредактируйте так, чтобы была ясность. Я написал этот вопрос и ответ для себя. Если Вы видите проблему, исправьте её или проголосуйте за закрытие

Comment: я бы отредактировал, дело в том, что из текста не ясно, что Вам нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следует зайти в БД следующей командой

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Затем, в самой базе следует создать нужные права и пользователей:

```
CREATE USER your_user  with encrypted password 'your-password';
```

Убедимся, что пользователь появился:

```
\du
```

Comment: `не может содержать символа -` - да запросто `create user "your-user" ...` и всего делов. Неудобно только кавычки писать постоянно будет.