# Не могу зайти под новым юзером

Tags: postgresql

На centos 8 стоит postgresql. Я проделываю все действия по созданию роли и бд [отсюда](https://community.vscale.io/hc/ru/community/posts/211866305-%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-PostgreSQL-%D0%BD%D0%B0-Ubuntu-16-04). Но, в итоге, после того как пытаюсь зайти под новым юзером, получаю это:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not initiate GSSAPI security context: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
could not initiate GSSAPI security context: Configuration file does not specify default realm
FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "username"
```

Как решить проблему?

Версия postgres: **12.3**

---

Я подразумеваю, что у Вас есть чистая БД и вы заходите в БД, как я описываю [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1175805/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2-postgres).

Comment: В "статье" полностью проигнорирован pg_hba.conf . Может быть за прошедшую кучу времени сопровождающий пакета начал иначе его из пакета конфигурировать или вы используете другой пакет (centos vs ubuntu, у сопровождающих которых весьма разные взгляды на построение пакетов postgresql)

Comment: @Мелкий я не понимаю, что мне с Вашим комментом делать. Подскажите, в какую сторону копать. Я вижу только отсылку к pg_hba.

Comment: Потому это и комментарий. Копать в строну pg_hba.conf https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html Смотреть какие auth-method указаны у вас и править на те которые нужны вам в действительности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Если кратко, то происходит примерно следующее:

При `psql -h localhost vscale_db username` `psql` пытается подключится к серверу по протоколу `tcp` на 127.0.0.1.

Сервер видит в своём `pg_hba.conf` строчку:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
```

и пытается «аутентифицировать» пользователя по протоколу ident. Для этого на хосте должен быть рабочий ident сервер и имя системного пользователя (см. `whoami`) от которого запущен psql должно совпадать с именем пользователя БД (`username`, в данном случае). Если это не удаётся, то идёт отказ авторизации.

#### Что делать:

Чтобы включить авторизацию по паролю нужно просто поменять auth-метод, например чтобы разрешить пользователю `username` подключаться к БД `vscale_db` и при этом у него запрашивался пароль в pg_hba.conf нужно добавить строчки (желательно в начало):

```
local   all             username                                md5
host    all             username        127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             username        ::1/128                 md5
```

При этом пароль при передаче будет шифроваться с помощью md5. Но для локальных подключениях это не к чему, так что вместо этого можно использовать `password`.

Чтобы все пользователи с localhost'а по паролю можно соответственно заменить `ident` на `password` в записях, которые уже есть в файле:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            password
host    all             all             ::1/128                 password
```

Чтобы пароль не спрашивался вовсе можно использовать `trust`.

После правки конфига также надо не забыть сказать postgres, чтобы он перезагрузил настройки из файла, на systemd-системе это можно сделать как-то так:

```
systemctl reload postgresql-12
```

Полноценный перезапуск (`restart`) СУБД не обязателен.

---

Подробности см. [в документации](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

Answer (score 0):

---

Скорее всего проблема с аутентификацией. В частности, ряд ссылок выводят на проблему с протоколом kerberos: [1](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5168121), [2](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/postgresql-sssd-kerberos-and-local-logins/7285), [3](https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/How-to-configure-user-authentication-using-kerberos-on-HAWQ-database?language=en_US), [4](https://postgrespro.ru/list/thread-id/1538448), [5](https://serverfault.com/questions/473465/cant-get-postgres-and-kerberos-gss-working-together), [6](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/gssapi-auth.html), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60675040/how-to-initiate-gssapi-in-potgresql), [8](https://www.highgo.ca/2020/03/26/postgresql-gssapi-authentication-with-kerberos-part-2-postgresql-configuration/), [9](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

---

В комментариях посоветовали обратить внимание на файл `pg_hba.conf`. У меня в системе он найден в `/pgdata/12/data/`.

---

Документацию по этому файлу можно найти здесь: [10](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/12/view-pg-hba-file-rules), [11](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/12/auth-pg-hba-conf), [12](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

---

Содержимое файла:

**pg_hba.conf**

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```

---

В ссылках [1](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5168121), [2](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/postgresql-sssd-kerberos-and-local-logins/7285), [6](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/gssapi-auth.html) приведены логи похожие на те, что указаны в текущем вопросе.

---

В [7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60675040/how-to-initiate-gssapi-in-potgresql) предлагается посмотреть в лог. Делается предположение, что основная проблема кроется в аутентификации, а не kerberos.

Лог найден по пути: `/pgdata/12/data/log`. Список файлов:

```
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres   75 Sep  4 22:47 postgresql-Fri.log
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres    0 Sep  7 00:00 postgresql-Mon.log
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres    0 Sep  5 00:00 postgresql-Sat.log
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres    0 Sep  6 00:00 postgresql-Sun.log
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres    0 Sep  3 00:00 postgresql-Thu.log
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 3304 Sep  8 17:23 postgresql-Tue.log
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 7584 Sep  9 16:34 postgresql-Wed.log
```

Заменил один из файлов на `postgresql-Wed-copy.log`. Осуществил действия в postgres. Ещё одного файла с логами не появилось. Делаю вывод, что данные логи могут иметь одношение не к текущему postgres, хотя логи очень похожи на мои последние действия.

При внесении операций в БД, в лог ничего не записывается. Есть подозрение, что я зашёл в какую-то не ту директорию.

---

Исходники могут лежать в разных местах:

- /usr/local/pgsql/data
- /var/lib/pgsql/$version
- /var/lib/postgresql/[version]/data/

У меня, одна из директорий эта: /var/lib/pgsql/$version

Там очень пусто:

```
total 4
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres   6 Jun 15 02:23 backups
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres   6 Jun 15 02:23 data
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 906 Jul  8 12:27 initdb.log
```

Директории пустые. Лог выглядит так:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /pgdata/12/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default time zone ... Europe/Moscow
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    /usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_ctl -D /pgdata/12/data -l logfile start


/usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_ctl -D /pgdata/12/data -l logfile start
```

---

Покажет, где лежат данные postgres следующая команда:

```
ps -ef|grep "postgres.*-D"
```

---

Файл с логами, который мы переименовали выше продолжает меняться даже с другим именем. Это странно.

---

Если зайти

```
sudo su
```

то окажется, что часть лога пропадает при попытке залогиниться так:

```
psql -h localhost vscale_db username
```

лог:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "username"
```

Comment: ты сознательно используешь такую аутентификацию (`peer`/`ident`) и коннектишься на localhost вместо локального сокета? хинт: для обоих этих методов имя пользователя БД должно совпадать с системным... а для второго должен ещё работать ident-демон (хз как с этим в systemd-системах)...

Comment: @Fat-Zer нет, не сознательно. Что Вы предлагаете? Можно детализировать?

Comment: например, заменить `ident` на `trust`, `password` или `md5` — в меру потребности безопасности (см. подробности в документации https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)... или создать пользователя с именем идентичным системному и соединяться просто `psql <database>`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer как будет выглядеть, например `trust` вход в БД? По ссылке не увидел этого

Comment: Просто пускать всех: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html

Comment: @Fat-Zer если не разберусь, окей. Оставлю такой кейс. Как, всё-таки решить проблему с доступом? Когда открытая БД -- это хорошо

Comment: дык, используй `password` или `md5`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer как? Ну, прямо для совсем тупи-глупи скажи.

Comment: ох... так не хотелось ответ писать >_<... сейчас что-нить накропаю ;)

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо